# sound design for an arcade like Tyrian game!

Tags: design, ideas, games

I am currently working on a project that reminds me of the old games Tyrian and Raptor (classic pew pew games). I have to do the sound design for all the sounds and the music so I'd like your oppinions on some topics.

1. do you usually start with other sounds and manipulate them as you want?
2. any ideas for the gun sounds? should i buy sounds and change them? or should i record sounds outside and try to make them "gun sounds". (not a chance of recording real weapons... but not a BIG problem cause the guns in this game are not "real")

Answer (score 2):

1. I like to start with a sound which best represents the sound I believe I should hear.  I then love to layer a couple of the sounds that compliment the original.  Wooshes work well.  If after, you feel like you need to add anything more, they eq'ing some of the sounds and you'll be able to create desired design effect.
2. There are plenty of free gun SFX out there if you look hard enough.  Even if its not perfect, like you said, they're not "real" weapons.  A couple of plugins should give you your desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

Worth checking out Plogue Chipsounds?